# How to add the '-pthread' option to g++ via Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, g++

I am compiling a multithreaded library using eclipse.

How can i add the -pthread or -pthreads option to the call made to g++ by eclipse?

Comment: Look at this and edit the Makefile: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14072969/67566

Comment: Hi thanks, but it is not a Makefile project. Its a normal eclipse one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The original answer that I wrote almost 2 years ago is now outdated; here is how to do it today.

Either right click on the project folder or *File > Properties*, then *C/C++ Build > Settings*. At the *GCC C++ Linker > Linker flags* add `-pthread` and finally hit the *Apply* button. That's all.

I have tested this with gcc 4.8 and Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu 14.04. Thank to Neil Traft for pointing it out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684536/how-to-add-the-pthread-option-to-g-via-eclipse/21686831?noredirect=1#comment56037434_21686831).

---

---

**The original answer from February 2014, now outdated:**

Either right click on the project folder or *File > Properties*, then *C/C++ Build > Settings*.

At the *GCC C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous* add `-pthread` to *Other flags* and hit the *Apply* button.

At the *GCC C++ Linker > Libraries*  click the icon with the green plus sign on the *Libraries* bar to add `pthread` and finally hit the *Apply* button.

This must solve it.

Note that you have to tell both the compiler and the linker that you are compiling a multi-threaded application (passing `-pthread` to the compiler and `-lpthread` to the linker).

Comment: As far as I can figure out, the option to the linker is `-pthread`, not `-lpthread`. I don't know if this is the "right" way to do it, but I got it to work by going to _GCC C++ Linker_ > _Miscellaneous_ and entering `-pthread` in the _Linker flags_ box.

Comment: @NeilTraft I wrote this answer almost 2 years ago. Apparently, Eclipse has changed and you do not have the *Other flags* anymore that I am referring to. Thanks for your feedback, I will update the answer soon.

Comment: @NeilTraft I have tested it and updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for letting me know that the answer has become outdated!

Comment: Please change `greed` to `green`.  The change is too tiny, so it wont let me edit.